# How to find out is a panel visible on page?

Tags: java, gwt

I use GWT 2.4.

I have a log of widgets on my web page, there are a huge tab panel with 13 elements, each element of tab has a panel. I use GWT framework. I have to make some logic when one of those elements is visible for user, how to implement it ???

I use Timer for "some logic" and to check whether the panel is visible or not.
I check :

```
if (somePanel.isVisible()) { do smth}
```

but it's not working because I also have other links and another elements and when I switch to another element it works but if I click on link - does not.
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: are you changing the visibility at run-time programmatically? Please try to share minimal testable code. How come we know that click is not working?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're using MVP,

You should do the display logic on page load through a model that you write to the place url. links change place so your views are reinitialized (if you don't have a clientFactory)

Anyway, you don't give any details on why it doesn't work with links and what means

> when I switch to another element it works